# Jenkins Shared Library instantiate util class and use in workflowscript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating my own Jenkins shared library to reuse some code between pipelines. I know how to create steps (really easy indeed) but I have a problem when I want to make accessible my "utils class" in the jenkinsfile (or WorkflowScript as Jenkins say in logs). 
I call "Util class" a groovy class located in folder src/my/domain/... that have many methods, for example, i want to create a log class like this:

```
# src/my/domain/group

package my.domain.group

class Console implements Serializable {

    def log(msg) {
        spit(msg, '\033[34m')
    }

    def error(msg) {
        spit(msg, '\033[31m')
    }

    def warning(msg){
        spit(msg, '\033[33m')
    }

    def success(msg){
        spit(msg, '\033[32m')
    }

    private def spit(msg, color){
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            echo color + msg + '\033[0m'
        }
    }

}
```

And then I try to instantiate in a file in /vars/library.groovy so can be accessed from the Jenkinsfile with some code as for example:

```
node("mynode"){
   console.log("Hello World!")
}
```

The idea is to avoid to instantiate the console in all the script and make it automatically, I have tried several things like

```
# vars/library.groovy

import my.domain.group.Console
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field String console = new Console()
```

or

```
# vars/library.groovy

import my.domain.group.Console

def load(){
    this.console = new Console() 
    // And also
    console = new Console()
}
```

But when trying to access from jenkins file I always get the error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: console for class: WorkflowScript

I understand that this means that the instance is not at the right scope so cannot be directly seen by the script but how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Looks like you are using your `vars` script incorrectly inside your Jenkinsfile, but I will try to solve some confusions :)

1. Groovy scripts defined in the `vars` directory are called by their file name as "custom" step in your Jenkinsfile. Assuming your script name stays `library.groovy`, your Jenkinsfile should look like this

   ```
   node ("mynode") {
        library("Hello World!")
   }
   ```

   or alternatively (since the parentheses are optional)

   ```
   node ("mynode") {
        library "Hello World!"
   }
   ```
2. Additionally `vars` scripts should only contain a single function named `call` and necessary imports. Since you want to pass your log message as a string, the `call` function additionally needs a parameter. So your `library.groovy` script in `vars` could look like this

   ```
   # vars/library.groovy

   import my.domain.group.Console

   def call(msg){
       Console console = new Console(steps) 
       console.log(msg)
   }
   ```

   Inside the `call` function you can use all basic Jenkins steps (`sh`, `bat`, etc.) as you could in your Jenkinsfile, plus any Groovy/Java classes imported via `import` (like your `Console` class).

   As you may have noticed, I also added a `steps` variable (which does not have to declared or instantiated manually) to the constructor of your `Console` class. This is necessary since you cant use any Jenkins steps directly in any of your classes defined in the `src` directory. Resulting, the method

   ```
   private def spit(msg, color){           
       ansiColor('xterm') {
           echo color + msg + '\033[0m'
       }
   }
   ```

   would not work, because `echo` is a Jenkins step. In order to use `echo` inside your class, you can pass the `steps` variable to the constructor and store it in another variable inside your class. Then you can call all Jenkins steps like `steps.echo "Hello World"`

   ```
   # src/my/domain/group

   package my.domain.group

   class Console implements Serializable {

        def steps

        Console(steps) {
            this.steps = steps
        }

        def log(msg) {
            spit(msg, '\033[34m')
        }

        def error(msg) {
            spit(msg, '\033[31m')
        }

        def warning(msg){
            spit(msg, '\033[33m')
        }

        def success(msg){
            spit(msg, '\033[32m')
        }

        private def spit(msg, color){
            ansiColor('xterm') {
                steps.echo color + msg + '\033[0m'
            }
        }
   }
   ```

That should make it work.

You should think about renaming your `library.groovy` inside `vars` though (for example `myLog.groovy`). Then your Jenkinsfile could look like this

```
node ("mynode") {
    myLog "Hello World!"
}
```

In order to use the other methods of your `Console` class, you can create additional scripts inside `vars`. Using them could look like this

```
node ("mynode") {
    myLog "Hello World!"
    myWarning "Hello World!"
    myError "Hello World!"
    mySuccess "Hello World!"
}
```

(im using the `my` prefix to avoid name collisions with already existing Jenkins steps. For example, the `error` step already exists and calling it in your Jenkinsfile will cancel your build)

For more info about shared libraries check out the Jenkins documentation at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

You can find a complete list of all basic Jenkins steps at https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/

Getting Jenkins and pipelines to work can be a huge hassle, but in the end it's worth it. I hope this wall of text helps a bit. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Adrian! I know about how to use the steps but i forgot to put this code in my example sorry :-). Reading your answer can i understand that i can't expose a instance of a class to be used directly in Jenkins pipelines? I know the option about create different steps for each of my methods in console but i think that is more clear to directly expose a instance of console from vars (i don;t know if this is possible) and then use it in the Jenkins file directly as i show in my example.

Comment: Well you could completely do without your `library.groovy` script inside `vars` and use the `Console` class directly in your Jenkinsfile. Just make sure to import your shared library via `@Library('[LIB_NAME]') _`, where `[LIB_NAME]` is the name of your library specified in your Jenkins settings, and your class via `import my.domain.util.Console` from inside your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Where is the steps-as-a-variable thing documented, I mean in "official" Jenkins Pipeline docs?

Comment: @6cef The steps variable is explained in greater detail [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps)